# How to implement extension method with generic type(T) that returns new T2(T)

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, extension-methods, ienumerable

Is there a way to produce a generic extension method that can take one type and convert it to another type by passing the source object of type into the constructor of the generic/unknown output type?

Here's the code I want to make more generic:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToPublicList(source As List(Of HashTag)) As List(Of WebServiceApiV1.PublicDataClasses.HashtagPublicInfo)

    Return (From ht In source Select New WebServiceApiV1.PublicDataClasses.HashtagPublicInfo(ht)).ToList()

End Function
```

Basically I want to do something to this effect:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToPublicList(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), destinationType As Type) As List(Of destinationType)

    Return (From x As T In source Select New destinationType(x)).ToList()

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) ?

It would look like this:

```
Return (From x As T In source Select Convert.ChangeType(x, destinationType)).ToList()
```

For this to work, destinationType must implement the interface [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx).